# Sql Trigger to "move" a field value to another field on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table as below, initial insert will add a value to "Cur_cost_unit" field where "Pre_cost_unit" will by default have a value of 0. When I update "Cur_cost_unit" to a new value, "Pre_cost_unit" needs to be updated with the old value of "Cur_cost_unit", essentially becoming the historical value of "Cur_cost_unit". I need to know if my trigger will update both fields at the same time, "Cur_cost_unit" getting new value and Pre_cost_unit" getting historical value of "Cur_cost_unit"?

My Table:

```
create table [Prod_Cost]

(
[Ent_id]        int              not null    IDENTITY,
[Prod_name]     nvarchar(50)     not null,
[Prod_code]     nvarchar(50)     not null    UNIQUE,
[Prod_id]       int              not null    CONSTRAINT [PK_PRODUCT_ID] PRIMARY KEY,
[Cur_cost_unit] money            not null    DEFAULT(0),
[Pre_cost_unit] money            not null    DEFAULT(0),
[Dte_Captured]  datetime         not null,
[Captured_by]   char(50)         not null
);
```

My Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Cur_CostUNIT_2PreV 
ON [Prod_Cost]

   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
DECLARE @Cur_cost_unit MONEY;
DECLARE @Prod_code NVARCHAR(50);

SELECT @Cur_cost_unit=i.[Cur_cost_unit] FROM inserted i;
SELECT @Prod_code = i.[Prod_code] from inserted i;

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
     UPDATE [Prod_Cost]
     SET [Pre_cost_unit] = (SELECT [Cur_cost_unit] FROM [Prod_Cost] where [Prod_code] = @Prod_code),
         [Cur_cost_unit] = @Cur_cost_unit
    END

END
GO
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: FYI - Triggers should handle the situation where multiple rows are change at once.  So there could be multiple rows in the inserted and deleted tables and your trigger should handle that correctly.

Comment: You need to rework this trigger to be set based and not use scalar variables like this.

Comment: in an update trigger.. `deleted` will have the previous values

Comment: You have a subquery in your update statement but there is no FROM. What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want something along the lines of (not tested)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_Cur_CostUNIT_2PreV 
ON [Prod_Cost]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
   UPDATE Prod_Cost
   SET Prod_Cost.Pre_cost_unit = deleted.Cur_cost_unit
   FROM Prod_Cost
   JOIN deleted
   ON Prod_Cost.Ent_id = deleted.Ent_id
```

Comment: Brilliant @IanKenney. I have it exactly as you have it now. apart from the ON clause..which I have as:    ON Prod_Cost.Prod_code = deleted.Prod_code

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for an update similar to this

```
UPDATE  pc
SET     pc.Pre_cost_unit = d.Cur_cost_unit
FROM    [Prod_Cost] pc
        JOIN INSERTED i ON i.Ent_id = pc.Ent_id -- new values
        JOIN DELETED d ON d.Ent_id = i.Ent_id -- previous values
```

Comment: to JamieD77 thanks for the deleted suggestion, haven't thought about that.

Comment: to Sean Lange, sorry, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: Not sure you really need the join to INSERTED as you are not using any data from there in this example

Comment: Considering your suggestion, @IanKenney , when the specific field "Cur_cost_unit" gets updated to a new value all the other fields needs first evaluate to true before the update actually happens. with the Inserted I will rather join on "Prod_code" as this will be a mandatory requirement and is unique during the update as "Ent_id" will be hidden. All of the updating will be captured by a C# application I will code later.

Comment: ps @SeanLange. I have updated my code to reflect what I was trying

Comment: @TrinityBob glad i could help.. or at least inspire other answers